# I need to delete all posts from my homepage & create a static front page

Tags: comments, blog

I want my homepage to be clean and without any posts or comments from my visitors. I have tried to do almost everything, but it doesn't work. I don't want people to discus anything, all they have to do is view who we are and how to reach us.
Can somebody tell me what to do.

Comment: Contact-us page as a [Static front page?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

Comment: Another option is to find a theme which includes a basic front page with widgets and use that as a guide to create your own front-page.php file that works with your theme.

Comment: Thank you for your fast replies. The thing is now, I have tried to make a new front page, called it home but I can make the page but it still sais "post your first comment, and I dont want to post anything. I have allso been inside the discussion section, and tried to unmark all the things but it doesn't say no comments or blogs...      I have choosen the Alexandria theme, should that be any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto settings>Reading> and look for "Front Page Displays". Select the "A static Page" radio button and below that click the drop down for "Front Page" and select which page you want for your home page.

Comment: It turned out that it was the Alexandria theme that made problems. Because when I did as you explaned, I couldn't see my backgroundpicture - instead there was a Alexandria theme picture. So now I changed the theme and my frontpage is just the way I want it to be, however Now on my contactpage, and any other new page I try to make, there is this stupid commentplace again, and with a lot of writing abot the HTML and what attributes and codes are legal. I would love to be abel to remove it all. I have been in discussion area and unchecked all the markings, I have choosen static page etc. pls help

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if you figured this out but let me know if you still need help.